# Text-overflow: ellipsis and overflow: scroll clip overflown text when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a strange issue with scroll and text-overflow behaviour in div. Obviously, the content after the ellipsis should become visible when there is extra space. But that doesn't happen.

CSS:

```
overflow: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vfG3.jpg)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please share a [example].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.